# Passing ID through href inside while php loop

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have this while loop working fine except for the last line in the table where i can't get the id to pass through correctly.
It does not give me any error, but when i hover over the "Modify" link it shows the correct ID and right after comes all the html code of the table.
It looks like it's not concatenating correctly.

There's the code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<table><tr><td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>" . 
         "<td>" . $row["product_name"] . "</td>" .
         "<td>" . $row["visible"] . 
         "<td><a href=\"modify.php?id=" . $row["id"] . ">Modify</a>" .
         "</td></tr></table>";
}
```

Comment: your `href` is not closing

Comment: View PHP error logs for debugging errors, and (not always useful but worth tying) view source code to see HTML errors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `echo` for each record, which is fine, but each time you echo a brand new table. What you probably mean is to echo only a new row. As others have suggested, your href is also not closed properly

Do something like:

```
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "<tr>
          <td> $row[id] </td>
          <td> $row[product_name] </td>
          <td> $row[visible] </td>
          <td><a href='modify.php?id=$row[id]'>Modify</a></td>
        </tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Note that because you're writing HTML, you don't need to concatenate many strings. You can have one long multi-line string. The browser will render the table just fine even if you have line breaks in your string. In addition, PHP can parse double-quoted strings and substitute variables for their string values, so you don't need to do `"<td>" . $row["id"]`; this works just fine: `"<td>$row[id]"`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
Fantastic!! It's working prime!!
Not only solved my issue(couldn't find the closing href) but also made it way more simple!!

Comment: @Willian that's good. Remember to select my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were missing a `"` and not closing your `href`. Below I have fixed it by adding the missing `"`. Also, I swapped out most of the double quotes for single quotes. That was my preference because it made it easier to read; I suspect you had trouble identifying the missing quote because of the use of only doubles.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<table><tr><td>' . $row["id"] . '</td>' .
             '<td>' . $row["product_name"] . '</td>' .
             '<td>' . $row["visible"] .
             '<td><a href="modify.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '">Modify</a>' .
             '</td></tr></table>';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! You're right! Too messy with too much double quotes!
Single quotes made it readable.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten to close the `href` attribute in your while loop.

Also, as the other answer notes, you are using `echo | print` to print a new table every time you run this loop, which might cause some wierd results.

Here is an example where you append everything to a string names `$table` and prints it out when you are done with the loop:

```
<?php
//Create start of table:
$table = '<table><tbody>';

//Fetch rows:
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    //append to the table:
    $table .= '<tr><td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . $row['product_name'] . '</td>' .
            '<td>' . $row['visible'] .   //You forgot the " under here
            '<td><a href="modify.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Modify</a>' .
            '</td></tr>';
}

//Append end of table:
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//print table:
print $table;
```

Comment: Thanks Kristian! One table with many rows instead of many tables!